# Laravel 5.4 site on IIS gets 404 on https requests

Tags: php, https, laravel-5.4, iis-8.5

I've set up a site that works perfectly on my IIS server when I connect via http; however, when I type in the address with https://, I get a 404 not found error.

I'm using Laravel 5.4
My web.config file (in my public folder) looks like this:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 3"      stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
<defaultDocument>
    <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="index.php" />
    </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

The basic settings in IIS point the site root to the public folder.

I have an https binding set up and there's nothing weird on the server's global settings or php settings that would be blocking https since we have several other non-Laravel php sites that work fine on https. If anyone could suggest a fix or at least a way I can see what IIS is doing on these rewrites with the http and https calls so I can see where it's going wrong and try to troubleshoot better. The standard logs are only showing my http calls, and those with pretty urls, not the actual urls IIS is using after rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. Turns out it was not a rewrite issue, it was an Azure issue. The port was in use by another VM in the same resource group, preventing me from opening the port on this machine (the other SSL sites on this machine had been using a different port, which is how they were able to run).